# Azure RBAC Permissions Tree?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

Is there a way to query Azure (via REST or CLI) to see which permissions are required/granted for certain actions?

For example, if I wanted to assign an SPN with `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write` permissions so it could create a VM, I would want to review what other permissions are granted/required before assigning it to said SPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Actions** property of a custom role specifies the Azure operations to which the role grants access. It is a collection of operation strings that identify securable operations of Azure resource providers. Operation strings follow the format of

`Microsoft.<ProviderName>/<ChildResourceType>/<action>`

Use `Get-AzureRmProviderOperation` (in PowerShell) or `azure provider operations show` (in Azure CLI) to list operations of Azure resource providers.

For more details, refer "[Create custom roles for Azure Role-Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles)".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to list dependencies in the way you describe. The Powershell cmdlet Get-AzureRmProviderOperation gives some good information on what permissions needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermprovideroperation?view=azurermps-5.0.0

[image]